# Why the code in a for loop is executed only in the first directory in a bash shell?

Tags: bash, for

Under a directory called `a` there are many subfolders where I want to do something. The same for all. I do the following but it applies only to the first subdirectory:

```
for i in "a/*"
    do
            #echo $i
            cd $i
            mkdir test
            mv *_no test
            touch aaa
            cd ..
    done
```

The above code I want to be executed in every directory under `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `glob`s, you should remove the quotes. If not, the `glob`s is not expanded.

So :

```
for i in a/*
```

Answer (score 4):

The first `cd` chdirs into the first directory (two levels of subdirs). And after that you can't `cd` into the second because you've only gone back one level so you're not back where you started from. But even then, you're looping over one single value: "a/*".

Since you've put quotes around that, it is not getting expanded.

However you've forgotten to put quotes around `$i`, so it does get expanded at that point as arguments to `cd`.

There are a lot of other problems with your code.

Some suggestions of improvements:

```
for i in a/*/; do
  (
    cd -- "$i" &&
      mkdir -p test || exit
    mv -- *_no test
    touch aaa
  )
done
```

Comment: Just to fill out the explanation a bit: the `(...)` construct sch uses here creates a subshell that localizes some actions, such as changing shell variables (not used here) and changing the current directory (used here). So when the subshell is finished, you're left at the same top-level directory you were in when you started the subshell. That's why `cd ../..` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting $i inside the loop doesn't do anything since `a/*/` is already expanded into words.  For example if `a/*/` expands to a/My Documents/, in the first loop `$i = a/My` and second loop `$i = Documents/`
Try

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read i; do
  (
    cd -- "$i" &&
      mkdir -p test || exit
    mv -- *_no test
    touch aaa
  )
done
```